# Unable to insert time type data into mysql in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a input field which takes input in the time format `'H:i A'` and should store in the mysql database of `time` type data.

I have converted the input by the `dateTime` function which looks like-

```
$sat_opened = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'H:i A',$_POST['sat_opened']);
$sat_opened_new = $sat_opened->format('H:i:s');
```

And query used to insert is -

```
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO biz_hours VALUES(DEFAULT, '$bid', 'Sat', '$sat_status', '$sat_opened_new', '$sat_closed','')")
```

Others Data are being inserted but for `opened` column it always inserts `12:00:00` . If i print the converted time (`echo $sat_opened_new`) then it prints time fine that should be in the MySQL time format like - `08:50:00` or `17:30:00`

What problem actually is there? Please help me to find out. Thanks

Comment: You are trying to insert the DateTime object rather than the formatted time.

Comment: Sorry, it was typing mistake. Updated in the question.

Comment: Have you tried just echoing it out instead of running the query?  `echo "INSERT INTO biz_hours VALUES(DEFAULT, '$bid', 'Sat', '$sat_status', '$sat_opened_new', '$sat_closed','')";`  That will allow you to at least see what is being executed.

Comment: A thought also, you should always declare the fields for compatibility purposes.  If the table structure changes, or if the values don't match the table structure, the values will not be inserted in the right place. Should be `INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('$value')`

Comment: it prints `INSERT INTO biz_hours VALUES(DEFAULT, '3', 'Sat', '2', '14:00:00', '10:00 AM','')` which looks fine but in the database it inserts `12:00:00` instead of `14:00:00`

Comment: Maybe it could be related to timezone diffs.

Comment: good point. Let me check.

Comment: Look at [`mysqli_error();`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see if the MySQL server has anything to say about your failed insert.

Comment: No. Data is being inserted successfully . Only problem is it is inserting different time.

Comment: What is the field type for $sat_opened_new

Comment: What is the table definition for biz_hours?  (i.e. "mysqldump -d biz_hours" from the command line, or "SHOW CREATE TABLE biz_hours" as a SQL command)

Comment: @Ethan22 . Field type is text and using bootstrap time input.

Comment: @GeorgeAdams `CREATE TABLE `biz_hours` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `biz_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `day` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
 `opened` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `closed` time DEFAULT NULL,
 `remarks` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

`

Comment: And what version of MySQL is it?  (`show variables like '%version%'`)

Comment: Did you try @Devon's suggestion that you format the statement like this: `INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('$value')`? This may simply be an issue of the values being inserted into the wrong column

Comment: @Ethan22 I tried. No change. @GeorgeAdams, MySql Version is `5.6.27` .

Comment: Very strange.  What if you just simplify the script for test purposes?  After making your connection, what open and closed values do you get from `mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO biz_hours VALUES(NULL, '$bid', 'Sat', '$sat_status', '12:34:56', '23:45:01', '')");`

Comment: @GeorgeAdams, Still it is inserting `12:00:00` :(

Comment: Keep narrowing the problem down.  Try this in PHP:  `mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO biz_hours (opened) VALUES ('12:34:56')");`  And if that still gives you an "opened" value of 12:00:00, go to a SQL console (from the command line or through phpMyAdmin) and run the query directly there: `INSERT INTO biz_hours (opened) VALUES ('12:34:56')`

Comment: Executing it in phpMyAdmin works fine. Now what may be the problem?

Comment: Did `mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO biz_hours (opened) VALUES ('12:34:56')");` work also?

Comment: Ya, it is also working.

Comment: So, keep working your way back from what DOES work until you find the point where it breaks.  For example, lengthen your query one or two fields at a time until you see where it breaks.  Try `mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO biz_hours (id, opened) VALUES (DEFAULT,'12:34:56')");`  Then change it to `mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO biz_hours (id, biz_id, opened) VALUES (DEFAULT,"$biz_id", '12:34:56')");` .  Keep going until you find the error again.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're successfully able to insert a date directly through phpMyAdmin: `INSERT INTO biz_hours (opened) VALUES ('12:34:56')` .  So you need to work back through your PHP query and debug it.  Start with the minimal working mysqli_query and begin adding back other fields (`biz_id`, `day`, `status`, etc.) until you encounter the problem again.  Perhaps one of your variables is not properly set.